# Error code MSB3191 cruise control build

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am recieving the below error when i'm trying to build it through cruise control: `code=MSB3191`

More details

```
<target name="Clean" startTime="08/07/2012 16:35:54" elapsedTime="00:00:00" elapsedSeconds="0" success="false">
      <project name="Clean" file="M:\ye66_Cruise_01_00_int\ISOS_DEMO_COMP\Cruise\RPTSolution\RPTSolution\RPTSolution.csproj" startTime="08/07/2012 16:35:54" elapsedTime="00:00:00" elapsedSeconds="0" success="false">
        <target name="CoreClean" startTime="08/07/2012 16:35:54" elapsedTime="00:00:00" elapsedSeconds="0" success="false">
          <message level="normal"><![CDATA[Creating directory "obj\Debug\".]]></message>
          <error code="MSB3191" file="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" line="3626" column="9" timeStamp="08/07/2012 16:35:54"><![CDATA[Unable to create directory "obj\Debug\". Access to the path 'obj\Debug\' is denied.]]></error>
        </target>
      </project>
 </target>
```

Comment: Can you please paste the msbuild tasks used in config files.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error from Msbuild. 
Sounds like Msbuild cannot create a directory, could it be a permission issue.

If you look at the project directory, does the account ccservice is running as have permission to create files and directories?